# Magento 2 setTemplate and add content to phtml template

Tags: layout, template, magento2.2.2, template-override

How to add bare HTML to a block e.g:

```
$block = $result->getLayout()->getBlock('category.description');
$block->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::myTemplate/blank.phtml')
->toHtml('<p>My Content</p>');
```

Is there a way to dynamically add content to a block perhaps without use of templates or any other way appreciate?

Answer (score 3):

You should try this

```
 echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Vendor\Module\Block\Myblock")- 
>setTemplate("My_Module::history-suite.phtml")->toHtml();
```

Comment: I know that Not what I was looking for! however I've found a solution thanks.

Comment: please Upvote. If you appreciate.

Comment: Helpful for others not for me

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution pretty simple.

```
$block = $result->getLayout()->setData(['test'=> 'Content here'])->getBlock('category.description');
$block->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::myTemplate/blank.phtml')
->toHtml();
```

Then my `blank.phtml`:

```
<?php print_r($this->getData()) ?>
```

It prints: `Array ( [test] => Content here [module_name] => Magento_Catalog )`